# Convert snake_case to PascalCase in .NET

Tags: c#, string

I want to write a C# extension method to convert from Python style variables (strings) to .NET style, for example:

```
"student_name" => "StudentName"
```

This is the extension method that I have written:

```
public static string PythonToDotNetStyle(this string str)
{
    var words = str.Split(new char[] { '_' });
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        words[i] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(words[i]);
    }

    return string.Join(string.Empty, words);
}
```

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to write this logic?

Comment: "more elegant" is highly subjective and opinionated, i'm afraid. (one step would be to use the ever-so-stylish foreach instead of for)

Comment: You mean more beautiful or more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The overload you’re using is `string[] Split(params char[]? separator)`, so you can write it without the explicit array:

  ```cs
  str.Split('_')
  ```
- `String.Join` with an empty string is `String.Concat`:

  ```cs
  return string.Concat(words);
  ```
- Functional style with `IEnumerable` extensions, yay

  ```cs
  public static string PythonToDotNetStyle(this string str)
  {
      return string.Concat(
          str.Split('_')
          .Select(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase)
      );
  }
  ```

Also, I would not make this an extension method (but I guess that’s subjective), and probably call it `SnakeCase…` (subjective, but with the reasoning that Python uses many different kinds of identifier formatting) `…ToPascalCase` (very subjective, but for a similar reason).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great, I also though of this variation which might be useful:

```
// student_name => StudentName
public static string SnakeCaseToPascalCase(this string str)
{
    string titleCase = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.Replace('_', ' '));
    return titleCase.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
}
```